# Rotate an embedded figure by 45 deg

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to rotate an embedded plot as a whole (i.e. the x axis of the plot should be in 45 degrees with x axis of embed plot). An example code providing a rotated embedded plot according to [How to rotate a simple matplotlib Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652631/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes) can be found below. The rotation does not seem to rotate the data but just the axis. In addition, I can't yet figure out how to move the embed plot within this figure

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist.floating_axes as floating_axes


def add_subplot_axes(ax,rect,axisbg='w'):
    fig = plt.gcf()
    box = ax.get_position()
    width = box.width
    height = box.height
    inax_position  = ax.transAxes.transform(rect[0:2])
    transFigure = fig.transFigure.inverted()
    infig_position = transFigure.transform(inax_position)
    x = infig_position[0]
    y = infig_position[1]
    width *= rect[2]
    height *= rect[3]
    subax = fig.add_axes([x,y,width,height])
    x_labelsize = subax.get_xticklabels()[0].get_size()
    y_labelsize = subax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_size()
    x_labelsize *= rect[2]**0.5
    y_labelsize *= rect[3]**0.5
    subax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=x_labelsize)
    subax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=y_labelsize)
    return subax

St=np.zeros((150,150))
k=np.random.sample(150)
np.fill_diagonal(np.fliplr(St), k)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(St,cmap='Greys')
plot_extents = 0, 10, 0, 10
transform = Affine2D().rotate_deg(45)
helper = floating_axes.GridHelperCurveLinear(transform, plot_extents)
ax1 = floating_axes.FloatingSubplot(fig, 111, grid_helper=helper)
ax1.plot(np.arange(0,10),(0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,10))
fig.add_subplot(ax1)

plt.show()
```

[image: The data are not displayed correctly. In addition, I can't figure out how to move the embed plot]

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652631/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate a simple matplotlib Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652631/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes)

Comment: I think yes, I still try to implement it, If it works I will upload the code.

Comment: Actually, I have trouble to rotate the embedded plot. In addition, I get a message that log axis is not supported,

Comment: Can you post what you tried along with the error?

Comment: I just did edit my post. Sorry for the delay answer

Comment: There is no error in the code right now but still, the data inside it are not properly plotted and in addition, I am not able to move the embed plot. @busybear