# Affine transformation using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, affinetransform

Let's say I want to draw an equilateral triangle.  One way is simply to plot its vertices, which can be at say (0,0), (1,0) and (1/2,\sqrt(3)/2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt
figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,1/2,0],[0,0,sqrt(3)/2,0],'k-')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

But supposing my y axis was tilted not at right angles to the x axis, but at 60 degrees.  This means that the vertices in that system would be (0,0), (0,1), (1,0).  I *should* be able to do this by some sort of affine transformation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D
from math import sqrt
figure, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,0],'k-')
ax....
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

where the sixth line would somehow transform the entire figure so that the right-angled triangle becomes equilateral.  But try as I might with `Affine2D`, I can't get it to work.

Another option - and I don't know if this would be possible in matplotlib - would be to redefine y so that (0,1) is mapped to (1/2, sqrt(3)/2).

Any help, or pointers to useful URLs would be great - thanks!

Comment: The transform works on data, not on the axes.

Comment: Thank you - so I have to apply the transform in the `ax.plot` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate a simple matplotlib Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652631/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes)

Comment: [This tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/specialty_plots/skewt.html) might be interesting.