# How to plot series of images onto a particular map

Tags: python, matplotlib, ggplot2, plot

I wanted to plot images in a particular pattern as shown in the image below

[image]

I wanted to understand what would be the best way to plot images using python. I used the following method in which plots images in a grid pattern.
output looks like this
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

img0 = f['B00'][i_ant, :, :]
img1 = f['B01'][i_ant, :, :]
img2 = f['B02'][i_ant, :, :]
img3 = f['B03'][i_ant, :, :]
    

img_arr = [img0,img1,img2,img3]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5., 5.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, 
                     nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                     axes_pad=0,  # pad between axes
                     )

for ax, im in zip(grid, img_arr):
    ax.imshow(im)
        

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does the plot produced by your code look like?

Comment: Just added the plot it looks

Comment: do the images need to be added in the same order that they appear in your example image (diagonal counter clockwise starting from the center)?

Comment: yes in the same order from the center

Comment: Are you interested in figuring out how to plot images in this particular pattern for any number of images or just for 4 images?

Comment: If it's only 4 images, you could use a 3×3 `GridSpec` (`GridSpec` doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html)) and just place your plots where you want them to be. It sounds more complicated if it's for any number of images.

Comment: Ideally, it is for 36 images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each additional level of the square spiral, two sides are added, except for the very last one where only one side is needed. The `i,j` positions increment or decrement with 1 at every step, and at each corner the direction is turned 90 degrees.

This is how it could work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 6
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 18), constrained_layout=True)
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=N * 2 - 1, nrows=N * 2 - 1)
i, j = N - 2 + N % 2, N - 1
dir_i, dir_j = 1, - 1
plot_num = 0
for k in range(1, N + 1):
    for _ in range(2):  # add two strokes of k subplots (only 1 when k==N)
        for _ in range(k):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(spec[i, j])
            ax.imshow(np.random.rand(3, 3))
            ax.set_xlabel(f'{plot_num} [{k}]', fontsize=18)
            plot_num += 1
            i += dir_i
            j += dir_j
        if k == N:
            break
        dir_i, dir_j = -dir_j, dir_i
plt.show()
```

[image: spiral of plots]

To copy the original numbering exactly, some concentric squares can be drawn. For odd `N`, the last square is quite irregular, with only 2 sides, where the last line jumps to the opposite side and with one square less than the rest.

For the weird numbering of 2 and 3, some renumbering can be introced:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 6
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 18), constrained_layout=True)
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=2 * N - 1, nrows=2 * N - 1)
plot_num = 0
for k in range(2, N + 2, 2):
    # i, j = N - 2 + N % 2, N - 1
    i, j = N - k + N % 2, N - 1
    dir_i, dir_j = 1, - 1
    for side in range(4):  # add four strokes of k subplots (only 2 when k==N)
        for _ in range(k - 1):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(spec[i, j])
            modified_plot_num = 5 - plot_num if plot_num in (2, 3) else plot_num
            ax.imshow(np.random.rand(6, 6), cmap='inferno')
            ax.set_xlabel(f'{modified_plot_num} [{k}]', fontsize=18)
            plot_num += 1
            i += dir_i
            j += dir_j
            if plot_num == N * N:  # for odd N, the very last cell should be skipped
                break
        if k == N + 1:
            if side == 0:  # for last side of uneven square: jump to the other side
                dir_i, dir_j = -dir_i, -dir_j
                i, j = i - 1, 2 * N - 2
            elif side == 1:
                break
        dir_i, dir_j = -dir_j, dir_i
plt.show()
```

[image: spiral of subplots, original numbering]

Comment: I think this could be the closest solution. Thank you so much. I might have to modify the positions to match the image numbers as shown on the map. Btw is it possible to tilt the images by 45 degrees? @JohanC

Comment: See [How to rotate a simple matplotlib Axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652631/how-to-rotate-a-simple-matplotlib-axes) about rotated subplots. It's not very flexible, so it doesn't make too much sense implementing it without knowing the exact usage.

Comment: Thanks for the link on rotated plots. Yeah for some reason 2 and 3 have a different order than others. hope I can change image number 4 to sit on top of 0.

Comment: As I have to make a single image after combining all 36 images in this map. so the positioning of these images is very essential for me.

Comment: This solution works like a charm. Thank you so much!