# Rotate whole 2D graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Have very simple 2D graph, couple of lines, some axis, title

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y1 = [3,5,4]
y2 = [4,3,5]
plt.plot(x, y1, 'g-')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'b.')
plt.title('Super')

plt.show()
```

Could I with simple command rotate whole graph? Around the center if possible?

Comment: Check the documentation https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/transformations.html

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv2gd.png

Comment: If so, you can use floating axes with an Affine2D transform: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21652631/13138364

Comment: @tdy I would be grateful if you could code for the image in the answer, and I'll accept it. THank you

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Actually it turns out this isn't quite correct. I just noticed the rotated `x` and `y` locations are not correct (e.g., `x` is supposed to be at `[1,2,3]`). I'll try to dig around some more.